# Bash script giving undesired output

Tags: bash

I am facing with the following bash script:

```
#! /bin/bash
processname=$1
x=1
while [ $x -eq 1 ] ; do
    ps -el | grep $processname | awk ' {if($15!="grep") print "The memory consumed by the process " $15 " is = "$9}  ' >> out.log
    sleep 30
done
```

and I am running this with :

```
$ ./myscript.sh Firefox
```

but when i see the output in the file, apart from the `firefox` process i am also getting information for `/bin/bash` process

```
The memory consumed by the process /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox is = 911328  
The memory consumed by the process /bin/bash is = 768
```

Can some one help me with this so that I only want to get information related to Firefox process and nothing else(/bin.bash etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal and because the `$processname` is `Firefox`. Since your command also monitors it, there is a process that uses it.

For example, try `ps -el | grep Firefox` and you will get two process lines matching (if you have one instance of Firefox running), one is Firefox, the other is the grep command looking for Firefox.

Piping your output in `grep -v /bin/bash'` should solve this. Eg:

```
ps -el | grep $processname | awk ...
```

becomes:

```
ps -el | grep $processname | grep -v 'grep' | awk ...
```

Comment: Ok i tried this and it also works :

     ps -el | grep $processname | awk ' {if($15!="grep") print "The memory consumed by the process " $15 " is = "$9}  ' | grep -v /bin/bash >> out.log

Answer (score 3):

The common trick is to change `grep Firefox` to `grep [F]irefox`. In this case, you can achieve it with

```
ps | grep '['${processname:0:1}']'${processname:1}
```

Answer (score 1):

You calling

```
ps -el | grep $processname | awk ' {if($15!="grep") print "The memory consumed by the process " $15 " is = "$9}  '
```

This means that you run awk and connect it's input with output of grep. Then grep is started and gets output of ps -el as input.

At the moment when bash will start ps you have grep and awk running.

Solution: run ps -el and remember it's output. Then run grep and awk. It should be like this:

```
ps -el > ps.tmp
grep $processname ps.tmp | awk ' {if($15!="grep") print "The memory consumed by the process " $15 " is = "$9}  ' >> out.log
```

Probably this could be done without using tmp file. Like `TMP=$(ps -el)`. But I don't know how to run grep filter on variable

Comment: You would use a bash here-string: `grep $processname <<< "$tmpvar" | ...`